# How do I get the id or index of a card in a list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, material-ui

I'm having trouble getting the id's for documents I've pulled from a MongoDB database and then displayed on a series of cards I've rendered using React and Material-Ui.

I've tried console-logging id in my functions and in the API's that I've set up, but I either get 'undefined', which is what the API returns, or a bunch of meta-data, which is what the delete function returns.

Here is my delete function:

```
  handleDelete = id => {
    console.log(id);
    console.log(this.props.match.params);

    // API.deleteArticle(this.props.match.params.id)
    //   .then(res => console.log(res.data))
    //   .catch(err => console.log(err));

    // this.props.history.push("/saved");
  };
```

Here is my API:

```
  deleteArticle: function(id) {
    console.log(id);
    return axios.delete("/api/articles/" + id);
  }
```

And here is how my card is rendered:

```
        {this.state.savedArticles.length ? (
          <Grid>
            {this.state.savedArticles.map((oneSavedArticle, i) => (
              <Card
                style={savedArticleCard}
                key={oneSavedArticle.id}
              >
                <Typography variant="h5">{oneSavedArticle.headline}</Typography>
                <Divider variant="middle" />
                <Typography>{oneSavedArticle.snippet}</Typography>
                <a href={oneSavedArticle.web_url} style={linkStyles}>
                  <Button style={buttonStyles}>READ IT</Button>
                </a>

                <button onClick={this.handleDelete}>Delete</button>
                {/* <DeleteDialogue id={props.articleFromDatabase.id} {...this.props} /> */}
              </Card>
            ))}
          </Grid>
) : (
```

The other part of that Ternary is just a default card that displays if the db is empty.

I'd like to be able to get the id so I can then delete the document from the database (and the card from the DOM).

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I've never used `axios`, but it seems like there should be an `await` or or some kind of callback here... `axios.delete("/api/articles/" + id);`

Comment: `handleDelete` needs to be passed an `id` as well. e.g. `this.handleDelete(oneSavedArticle.id)`

Comment: Also, not sure if you're using mongoose or mongoclient. If you're using mongo client, the string `id` is not what you need. You need to convert the `_id` string into a Mongo `ObjectId`. It's not clear from your question if the ID is coming back properly, so I'm assuming it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not passing the ID to the `handelDelete` function, you need to update your code as follows:

```
{this.state.savedArticles.length ? (
              <Grid>
                {this.state.savedArticles.map((oneSavedArticle, i) => (
                  <Card
                    style={savedArticleCard}
                    key={oneSavedArticle.id}
                  >
                    <Typography variant="h5">{oneSavedArticle.headline}</Typography>
                    <Divider variant="middle" />
                    <Typography>{oneSavedArticle.snippet}</Typography>
                    <a href={oneSavedArticle.web_url} style={linkStyles}>
                      <Button style={buttonStyles}>READ IT</Button>
                    </a>

                    <button onClick={() => this.handleDelete(oneSavedArticle.id)}>Delete</button>
                    {/* <DeleteDialogue id={props.articleFromDatabase.id} {...this.props} /> */}
                  </Card>
                ))}
              </Grid>
    ) : (
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't pass the `id` to the `handleDeleteFunction()` here:

```
<button onClick={this.handleDelete}>Delete</button>
```

Thats why `id` is always `undefined` if you log it in `handleDeleteFunction()`.

You have two options to pass the `id` properly.

**Option 1: Use arrow function**

```
<button onClick={() => this.handleDelete(oneSavedArticle.id)}>Delete</button>
```

**Option 2: Use bind()**

```
<button onClick={this.handleDelete.bind(this, oneSavedArticle.id)}>Delete</button>
```